# Chef and multi-node-ec2 tutorial

Tags: chef-infra

I'm learning chef and following the [#learnchef tutorials](https://learnchef.opscode.com/common-use-cases/multi-node-ec2/) through, specifically the EC2 multi-node EC2 one. I am struggling to understand what it means in a specific section.

In section 10, it says:

```
Next, we need to drop configuration files for Redis, specifically, we need the hostname. We can leverage Chef search for this:

redis_server = search(:node, 'role:redis').first

template "#{node['my_app']['root']}/shared/config/redis.yml" do
  source        'config/redis.yml.erb'
  owner         node['apache']['user']
  group         node['apache']['group']
  mode          '0755'
  variables(
    :host => redis_server['ec2']['local_ipv4']
  )
end
```

And then, `Add the associated template in templates/default/config/redis.yml.erb:`

```
# This file was created by Chef for <%= node['fqdn'] %>
# Do NOT modify this file by hand!

host: "<%= @host %>"
```

Obviously I understand the latter, but what does it mean: "drop configuration files for Redis"?

Am I supposed to be running something as a command or does that need to go in my recipes file?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? It's okay to answer your own question. Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 1):

When they say drop they mean setup the template file in /templates/default/config/redis.yml.erb and allow the Chef recipe to create it on the machine your installing redis.